# AJAX request in jQuery get function, variable issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm struggling with a jQuery Ajax call. Please help!

```
var email = patrick@patrick.com;
var password = patrick;

$.get("server.php", {option:"signup", email:"email", password:"password}, function(req){
alter (req);}
```

So I'm sending two variables to the server, email and password. But I'm sending the signup option in text. How do I send the jQuery variables? The text seems to be working but not the email and password variables. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `password` and `email`.

```
{option:"signup", email:email, password:password}
```

Answer (score 3):

> how do i send the jquery variables?

There are no "jquery variables". The language is called JavaScript.

> `{option:"signup", email:"email", password:"password"}`
>
> so i'm sending two variables to the server, email and password

No, you send the 3 string literals `"signup"`, `"email"` and `"password"` to the server. To use the variables you declared above, use their names without quotes.

> `var email = patrick@patrick.com;`
>   `var password = patrick;`

Don't forget the quotes here, when assigning *strings* to the variables!

```
var email = "patrick@patrick.com";
var password = "patrick";
```